# composer update:Call to a member function name() on array

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-livewire

when I launch the composer update it gives me the following error:

```
Call to a member function name() on array

 at vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LivewireServiceProvider.php:129
        125▕     protected function registerRoutes()
        126▕     {
        127▕         RouteFacade::post('/livewire/message/{name}', HttpConnectionHandler::class)
        128▕             ->middleware(config('livewire.middleware_group'))
      ➜ 129▕             ->name('livewire.message');
        130▕ 
        131▕         RouteFacade::post('/livewire/upload-file', [FileUploadHandler::class, 'handle'])
        132▕             ->middleware(config('livewire.middleware_group'))
        133▕             ->name('livewire.upload-file');
    
          [2m+8 vendor frames [22m
      9   [internal]:0
          Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}()
    
          [2m+5 vendor frames [22m
      15  artisan:37
          Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I don't understand. In the specific :

```
     at vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LivewireServiceProvider.php:129
    125▕     protected function registerRoutes()
    126▕     {
    127▕         RouteFacade::post('/livewire/message/{name}', HttpConnectionHandler::class)
    128▕             ->middleware(config('livewire.middleware_group'))
  ➜ 129▕             ->name('livewire.message');
    130▕ 
    131▕         RouteFacade::post('/livewire/upload-file', [FileUploadHandler::class, 'handle'])
    132▕             ->middleware(config('livewire.middleware_group'))
    133▕             ->name('livewire.upload-file');

      +8 vendor frames 
  9   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Livewire\LivewireServiceProvider))

      +5 vendor frames 
  15  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I use composer version 2020-10-30_22-31-58-1.10.17

Comment: This has nothing to do with composer specifically, but an uncaught exception in your Laravel code. Its not much to go on here, but that service provider doesn't look like the latest version - which Livewire version are you running? Have you attempted to clear your cache (although I doubt it'll help)?

Comment: Looks like this was fixed in 2.3.11. https://github.com/livewire/livewire/releases/tag/v2.3.11

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a new version of livewire is causing this issue. I downgraded to v2.3.8 and I'm back up and running.